# How intercept coming frames from camera

Tags: qt, qt5, video-capture

I capture video from webcam and record it using QMediaRecorder.

Which way existed that I can do 2 below actions?

1. Catch every frame coming from camera
2. Manipulate that frame

One of usecases that I want to do is, magnifying the video before saving on disk (and also show it when saving)
I use QVideoProbe but I’m not lucky.
In blow code, “ctrl” is null, so there is no signal from video probe.

```
bool res = videoProbe->setSource(mediRecorder);
QMediaObject *obj = mediaRecorder->mediaObject();
QMediaService *srv = obj->service();
QMediaControl *ctrl = srv->requestControl<QMediaVideoProbeControl*>();
```

Comment: Just a thought, Opencv might help you out. It integrates well into QT and can easily catch each frame and preform powerful manipulations.

Comment: Thanks Gibby. But I think Qt and opencv can not work together when using media recorder of qt. I find out the solution is implementing QAbstractVideoSurface and set as viewfinder i QCamera